# Оказывает ли PK положительное влияние на скорость смены типа у колонок таблицы?

Tags: sql-server

В общем, есть таблица на 3 000 000 записей с большим кол-вом колонок с типом `text`.

Я запустил последовательный ALTER Table на них:

Сначала измеряю максимальную длину изменяемой колонки, а потом подсовываю это все в динамический запрос, что бы кастануть в `nvarchar` нужно длинны.

Так вот, процесс подозрительно долго идет...

Может ли какой-то профит оказать создание на таблице PK? Сейчас эта таблица вообще без индексов.

Comment: Мне интересно, а почему так много колонок?

Comment: Никакие индексы не ускорят, скорее только замедлят. Создайте таблицу нужной структуры, перенесите туда данные и переименуйте.

Comment: @doox911 имеется ввиду записей =)

Comment: @DenisRubashkin А разве это не зоймет столько же времени, что я итерационно по 1 колонки альтертебаю?

Comment: @iluxa1810 если вы формат колонок меняете, то таблица физически в файле вся перезаписывается. разве что при обрезке последней колонки мб это не потребуется. перелить в гораздо быстрее.

Comment: Думаю, что один запрос для всех _text_-столбцов сразу быстрее сработает, чем несколько отдельных для каждого столбца. В конце желательно сделать `ALTER TABLE [TableName] REBUILD`.

Comment: @i-one Вроде, пакетно 1 запросом поменять нельзя... Только по очереди.

Comment: @iluxa1810, хм, и правда (поменять нельзя, добавить можно), был уверен, почему-то, что делал так когда-то.